# Compiling software with the same options as a previous install

Tags: compiling, make

I want to compile and install a software on a new VM. The software was installed successfully on a different VM by a different admin, but I want to duplicate the exact command with the options that he used. Is this possible? BTW, the folder from where he ran `./configure` is still intact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the whole directory where `./configure` was previously run is wholly intact, then within that directory will be a file called `config.status`.  The `config.status` file is generated when `./configure +args` is run, and it records the arguments that are run.  If you want to do everything exactly the same, and the new system has all the dependencies in place, you have several options.

- you can tar/gzip the whole directory, copy the tarball to the new system, unpack it, and run `make install` to simply re-install the previously made objects.  This should work if the system is similar enough (architecture/OS).
- you can tar/gzip the whole directory, copy the tarball to the new system, unpack it, and run the `./config.status` script redo all the previous `./configure` work, allowing you to run a clean `make`, `make test`, and `make install`.
- you can also do a completely clean build using the previous admin's exact arguments, by running `cp config.status myconfigure`, `make clean`, `make distclean`, and then running `./myconfigure` to redo *all* the work.

The last option would work even if you were going between different linux distros, or from linux to solaris or freebsd, or 32-bit to 64-bit, provided that all the software's dependencies were met beforehand.

By copying `config.status` to a new filename like `myconfigure`, you preserve that file through any `make clean`, or `make distclean` commands.